# Getting many errors in firebase cloud messaging app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Update:
The repository with the whole code is below:
https://github.com/akash07k/Clouding
So, I'm developing my FCM app and I'm getting many errors as soon as I allow the notifications for the app.
First error is about "onTokenRefresh" is not being a function.
I searched a lot about each error message but couldn't find any clue.
I'll be very thankful if someone can help me please.
I'm providing both the errors and whole code below:
Below are the errors:

```
(index):73 Uncaught ReferenceError: onTokenRefresh is not defined
    at initFirebaseMessagingRegistration ((index):73)
    at (index):31
(index):46 Got notification permission
(index):55 Didn't get notification permission TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vapidKey')
    at updateVapidKey (updateVapidKey.ts:27)
    at getToken$1 (getToken.ts:42)
    at getToken (api.ts:114)
    at (index):47
(index):65 Didn't get notification permission FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at registerDefaultSw (registerDefaultSw.ts:43)
    at async updateSwReg (updateSwReg.ts:28)
    at async getToken$1 (getToken.ts:43)
Error
(index):73 Uncaught ReferenceError: onTokenRefresh is not defined
    at initFirebaseMessagingRegistration ((index):73)
    at (index):31
(index):46 Got notification permission
(index):55 Didn't get notification permission TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vapidKey')
    at updateVapidKey (updateVapidKey.ts:27)
    at getToken$1 (getToken.ts:42)
    at getToken (api.ts:114)
    at (index):47
Error
firebase-messaging-sw.js:4 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js' failed to load.
    at http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js:4:1
(index):65 Didn't get notification permission FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at registerDefaultSw (registerDefaultSw.ts:43)
    at async updateSwReg (updateSwReg.ts:28)
    at async getToken$1 (getToken.ts:43)
```

Code:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clouding</title>
    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-analytics.js";
        import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-messaging.js";
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDOVN1qOGzsD6AI-2jA05LpfQIJ5aoCuD4",
            authDomain: "clouding-aa740.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "clouding-aa740",
            storageBucket: "clouding-aa740.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "1059589787087",
            appId: "1:1059589787087:web:cdd636057d2a921ccdd6ba",
            measurementId: "G-CD2BEK39LZ"
        };
        window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            switch (e.target.id) {
                case "btnPermissions":
                    initFirebaseMessagingRegistration();
                    break;
            }
        });
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        //        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        const messaging = getMessaging(app);


        function initFirebaseMessagingRegistration() {

            Notification.requestPermission()
                .then(function () {
                    messageElement.innerHTML = "Got notification permission";
                    console.log("Got notification permission");
                    return getToken();
                })
                .then(function (token) {
                    // print the token on the HTML page
                    tokenElement.innerHTML = "Token is " + token;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    errorElement.innerHTML = "Error: " + err;
                    console.log("Didn't get notification permission", err);
                });

            // Don't forget your vapidKey here
            getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "293kfk" })
                .then((t) => {
                    tokenElement.innerHTML = "Token is " + r;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    errorElement.innerHTML = "Error: " + err;
                    console.log("Didn't get notification permission", err);
                });

            onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
                console.log("Message received. ", JSON.stringify(payload));
                notificationElement.innerHTML =
                    notificationElement.innerHTML + " " + payload.data.notification;
            });
            onTokenRefresh(function () {
                messaging.getToken()
                    .then(function (refreshedToken) {
                        console.log('Token refreshed.');
                        tokenElement.innerHTML = "Token is " + refreshedToken;
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        errorElement.innerHTML = "Error: " + err;
                        console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
                    });
            });
            console.log("clicked");
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Welcome to Clouding</h1>
        <div id="token" style="color:lightblue" role="alert"></div>
        <div id="message" style="color:lightblue" role="alert"></div>
        <div id="notification" style="color:green" role="alert"></div>
        <div id="error" style="color:red" role="alert"></div>
        <script>
            messageElement = document.getElementById("message")
            tokenElement = document.getElementById("token")
            notificationElement = document.getElementById("notification")
            errorElement = document.getElementById("error")
        </script>
        <button id="btnPermissions">Enable Firebase Messaging</button>

    </main>

</body>
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
// Import and configure the Firebase SDK

// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-analytics.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-messaging.js');

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDOVN1qOGzsD6AI-2jA05LpfQIJ5aoCuD4",
  authDomain: "clouding-aa740.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "clouding-aa740",
  storageBucket: "clouding-aa740.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1059589787087",
  appId: "1:1059589787087:web:cdd636057d2a921ccdd6ba",
  measurementId: "G-CD2BEK39LZ"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// Keep in mind that FCM will still show notification messages automatically 
// and you should use data messages for custom notifications.
// For more info see: 
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onTokenRefresh` doesn't exist in the new Firebase SDK 9 version. I have also searched for it or alternatives in the [API References](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/messaging_.md#@firebase/messaging) but could not find any.

Can you pls uncommend the part with `onTokenRefresh` and see if at least some errors go away.

You also don't need to request the permission on your own. `getToken` will do that autimaticaly.

UPDATE:

How it worked on my side. Remove all code from `firebase-messaging-sw.js` (at least for now) but keep the empty file. And put valid Firebase Cofnig data (also a valid `vapidKey`):

This is with the configs of one of my projects and it worked out:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clouding</title>
    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-analytics.js";
        import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-messaging.js";
        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
           apiKey: 'AIzaSyBQAmNJ2DbRyw8PqdmNWlePYtMP0hUcjpY',
            authDomain: 'react-most-wanted-3b1b2.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://react-most-wanted-3b1b2.firebaseio.com',
            projectId: 'react-most-wanted-3b1b2',
            storageBucket: 'react-most-wanted-3b1b2.appspot.com',
            messagingSenderId: '258373383650',
            appId: '1:258373383650:web:b49ad5dd28da999a',
        };
        window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            switch (e.target.id) {
                case "btnPermissions":
                    initFirebaseMessagingRegistration();
                    break;
            }
        });
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        //        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
        const messaging = getMessaging(app);

        function initFirebaseMessagingRegistration() {

            // Don't forget your vapidKey here
            getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "BEthk1-Qmoh9opZbi1AUZpxANTu6djVRDph4MLpyO2Qk6Dglm1Sa8Yt_pYi4EhYi3Tj-xgLqUktlbNuP_RP6gto" })
                .then((t) => {
                    tokenElement.innerHTML = "Token is " + t;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    errorElement.innerHTML = "Error: " + err;
                    console.log("Didn't get notification permission", err);
                });

            onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
                console.log("Message received. ", JSON.stringify(payload));
                notificationElement.innerHTML =
                    notificationElement.innerHTML + " " + payload.data.notification;
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Welcome to Clouding</h1>
        <div id="token" style="color:lightblue" role="alert"></div>
        <div id="message" style="color:lightblue" role="alert"></div>
        <div id="notification" style="color:green" role="alert"></div>
        <div id="error" style="color:red" role="alert"></div>
        <script>
            messageElement = document.getElementById("message")
            tokenElement = document.getElementById("token")
            notificationElement = document.getElementById("notification")
            errorElement = document.getElementById("error")
        </script>
        <button id="btnPermissions">Enable Firebase Messaging</button>

    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the token:
[image]

Comment: bro, I removed the onTokenRefresh part and that error is now gone.
But other errors are still there
Actually the sad thing is that googles quickstart example repo for firebase doesn't contain the code for the newer (moduler) sdk.

Comment: Can you pls update the question with the new error messages.

Comment: tarik-huber Errors are same as I've stated in my question. only the error related to onRefreshToken gone

Comment: Can you pls remove also ` Notification.requestPermission()` and the other parts of it. Can you also ensure that the Notification permission for the domain you try it on are reset to default or accepted.

Comment: I did this bro, but same errors. I feel something is wrong with my firebase-messaging-sw.js, but unable to spot any problem. should I share the complete code in a repo or file so that you can take a look at it?

Comment: Yes pls. I will take a look on it.

Comment: Hi bro, I've upload it to the repo: https://github.com/akash07k/Clouding Updated the same in my question too. @tarik-huber

Comment: I have update my answer. Pls copy my code into your project. There where also smaller bugs inside (typos)

Comment: Hi bro,
@tarik-huber
I'm successfully able to get the token now, but still getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vapidKey')
Also, why I am required to empty the firebase-messaging-sw.js file? (I've pushed the updated code to the repo. You can check it)

Comment: Do you need to customize the messages you get from Firebase? You would also only be able to do it with `data` notifications. So if you don't plan to do it that file can be empty. In your code example the vpidKey ist still not valid `vapidKey: "293kfk" `

Comment: Yes, I need to customize the data messages in some instances

Comment: Can ypu pls first add a valid vapidKey. Without that you can't even come to the customatisation.

Comment: Yes bro, I've added it in the repo. You can check now.

Comment: Now I'm successfully able to get the token but not receiving any notification. If I'm adding the content to firebase-messaging-sw.js file then getting following error after clicking on "enable firebase messaging" button: Error: FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

Comment: Update: Verified again and now getting the above error without firebase-messaging-sw.js file too. Also, when I'm sending the notification to the app, then getting this error:

Comment: fcmregistrations.goo…45qFPDOp7C-LYs1JN:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Warning
token-manager.ts:67 FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while unsubscribing the user from FCM: FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while unsubscribing the user from FCM: Requested entity was not found. (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed). (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed).
    at requestDeleteToken (requests.ts:143)
    at async getTokenInternal (token-manager.ts:61)

Comment: You are using my `validKey` you need to get the one from your project. You get it in the Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging -> on the bottom Web Push Certificates

Comment: update: Created another question because this discussion was getting longer in comments and original issue of this question is resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212518/unable-to-receive-the-notification-in-the-app-and-getting-errors @tarik-huber

Comment: I'm using my key only, I've updated the same in the code.

Comment: Update: yes, I forgot to update the vapidKey at one place. updated and the error is now gone which was coming after clicking on "enable firebase messaging" button, however, still unable to receive the notification/message.